# How can I get an instance in another class in Java?

Tags: java, class, instance

I am learning javaFX but I can't figure out how to get an instance that I created in another controller into my new Controller.

Class of Auto

```java
package com.example.test1;

public class Auto {
    private static String merk;
    private static double prijs;

    public Auto(String merk, double prijs) {
        this.merk = merk;
        this.prijs = prijs;
    }

    public String getMerk() {
        return merk;
    }

    public double getPrijs() {
        return prijs;
    }
}
```

My controller of my main fxml

```java
import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {

    public Label random;
    public Button btn1;
    public static Auto auto;

    public void maakNieuweAuto() {
        auto = new Auto("bmw", 900);
    }

    public void button() throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Auto.fxml"));
        Stage window = (Stage) btn1.getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 500));
    }
}
```

My controller of my second fxml

```java
package com.example.test1;

import javafx.scene.text.Text;

import static com.example.test1.Controller.auto;

public class AutoController {

    public Text Merk;
    public Text Prijs;

    public AutoController() {
            Merk.setText(auto.getMerk());
            Prijs.setText("" + auto.getPrijs());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can switch this `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Auto.fxml"));` to the version where you create a load, then you can get the controller from that.

Comment: Here it is [FXMLLoader](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.net.URL)) Create a loader, then use [getController](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getController()) and you'll get the related controller.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your controller of your main fxml

Public Controller (){
}

And this on new controller fxml
Controller controller = new Controller ();
controller.maakNieuweAuto();

Comment: Thanks for the help. But my question wasn't really clear excuse me. I want to get the merk and prijs out of a textfield where the user can type it in. All this I have but I can't get to the instance if it is created in another class :(. But thanks for the help I really appreciate it.